# perform calculation according to formula and object as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have created getResult function to perform calculation according to formula.  is there any way to perform this calculations 
please let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks in Advance

```
let formula = "a*b";
let parameters = {a:3,b:4}
let getResult = function(formula, parameters){ 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Though "eval" is something to be avoided.

```js
let formula = "a*b";
let parameters = {a:3,b:4}
let getResult = function(formula, parameters){ 
  let cal = [...formula].map(d => parameters[d] || d).join('')

  return eval(cal)
}

console.log(getResult(formula, parameters))
```

Comment: don't forget kids, eval is evil

Answer (score 1):

A simple calculator that doesn't rely on `eval`:

```js
let formula = "a*b";
let parameters = {a:3,b:4}

function getResult(formula, parameters){ 
  const operator  = formula.match(/[+-\/*]{1}/)[0];
  const {a, b} = parameters;
  switch(operator) {
    case '+': return a + b;
    case '-': return a - b;
    case '*': return a * b;
    case '/': return a / b;
  }
}

const result = getResult(formula, parameters);
console.log(result);
```